# Ubuntu Server Installation and RAID configuration

Tags: server, hard-drive, raid

I purchased some components for building a NAS, on which I would like to install Ubuntu Server.
My configuration is: 2 6TB HDDs and 1 500GB HDD.
My question is: is 
How can I install the operating system on the 500GB and create a RAID1 for the other two hard drives?
Then i would use samba for connect folder in the 6tb drive

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Opinion based questions are not encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the pair of 6TB HDDs and install Ubuntu Server after downloading it from https://ubuntu.com/download/server

Once install completes, shut down, reconnect the 6 TB HDDs, and follow the instructions for your RAID controller to configure the drives for RAID-1.